# Unable to select Python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Code on a Mac uses 2.7 version regardless of "python.pythonPath" setting explicitly set to /usr/local/bin/python3. Selecting interpreter interactively via command palette has no effect either.

Running python in the terminal launches 3.6 which should be picked up by the Code with default "python.pythonPath" setting, but it is not.

No matter what I do Code keeps using 2.7.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have a Mac to try it on but IIRC your files need a shebang i.e. the first line should read `#!/usr/bin/env python3` you also need to make sure that you don't have dos line endings.

Comment: Are you following this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments?

Comment: Yes, I followed instructions for setting interpreter in this doc - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments.

Comment: @SteveBarnes adding the directive did the trick - thank you! Would be nice to not have to do that though.

Comment: The extension doesn't control the terminal, so if you're directly executing your scripts then the extension has nothing to do with that and so it can't force it to use the interpreter you specified.

Comment: @BrettCannon I am executing from within VS Code.

Comment: @vladvino The trick is to make that line, (and a following one with `#encoding utf-8`) a part of your standard template for a new file. The good news is that on almost any thing but Windows you don't have to have a .py extension so you can run `niffty_util` _providing it is set to executable_ without having to type  `niffty_util.py` or  `python niffty_util` - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) for the history (which goes back to 1979/1980).

Comment: @vladvino I have moved my comments above to answers as comments are not preserved for all time _(nor marked as the answer)_.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but you could **change the "python.pythonPath" setting from** `usr/bin/local/python3` **to** `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: The original post had a typo - now corrected. python.pythonPath was always set to /usr/local/bin/python3.

Answer (score 0):

Your files need a shebang i.e. the first line should read:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
```

*you also need to make sure that you don't have dos line endings*

It is also a good idea to have a second line reading:

```
#encoding utf-8
```

The trick is to make these lines a part of your standard template for a new file or to have them in your editors snippets.

The good news is that on almost any thing but Windows you don't have to have a .py extension so you can run `niffty_util` *providing it is set to executable* without having to type `niffty_util.py` or `python niffty_util` - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for the history (which goes back to 1979/1980).

*Moved from comments to preserve.*

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple versions of python, I suggest you use virtual environments. These define which version of python you use and keeps everything straight. If you used Anaconda to download python, the Anaconda documentation is very clear on how to create and run from a virtual environment. If you didn't use anaconda, Unix has a simple way to define virtual environments.

I have virtual environments for python 2.7.13 and python 3.6.  I can just activate the appropriate environment depending on which version of python I wish to use. I use this and I'm running VScode on my iMac.